# Как связать 2 таблицы список пользователей и список видео

Tags: php, mysql

В одной таблице список пользователей (поля: id, логин, пароль, права), а вторая это таблица с видео. То есть будет штук 10 видео и у разных пользователей показываются разные видео. Может быть  1 видео а может и все 10. 
Так же должна возможность администратору добавлять новые видео и указывать какие видео кому смотреть. 
Кто может натолкнуть на идеи? а то в голову что-то не лезет ничего

Comment: три таблицы. Связь многие ко многим. Таблица Пользователей. Таблица Видео. И таблица связи видео-пользователь, где только три столбца - id, user_id, video_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Первая таблица: id, login, password, role
Вторая таблица: id, name_video и т.д.
Третья таблица: id, id_user, id_video
```